# Eliminating all floating point values from a list in python?

Tags: python, list

How can I remove floating point numbers from a list?
input = [3.2, 0.0, 3, 4]
output = [3, 4]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isinstance`:

```py
lst = [3.2, 0.0, 3, 4]

output = [x for x in lst if not isinstance(x, float)]
print(output) # [3, 4]
```